# How to run protoc correctly with different file import?

Tags: proto, protoc

**My main file to generate has these `import` :**

```
import "protos/google_annotations.proto";
import "protos/nakama_annotations.proto";
import "protos/nakama_api.proto";
```

**The folder structure :**

```
├── lib
    ├── protos
         ├── google_annotations.proto
         ├── nakama_annotations.proto
         ├── nakama_api.proto
         ├── apigrpc.proto   <--- this is the file to generate.
```

**The highlight syntax is ok.(Android studio)**

**The 2 cases that i got error are :**

1.

- Command run in `protos` directory
- Run `protoc apigrpc.proto --java_out=. --proto_path=.`
- Get this error

  ```
   protos/google_annotations.proto: File not found.
   protos/nakama_annotations.proto: File not found.
   protos/nakama_api.proto: File not found.
  ```

2. Specify all import files

- Command run in `protos` directory
- Run

  `protoc apigrpc.proto --java_out=. --proto_path=google_annotations.proto --proto_path=nakama_annotations.proto --proto_path=nakama_api.proto`
- Get this error `apigrpc.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path`

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what's wrong. It's about `import`.

I have to remove the prefex `protos` because the import file is in the same level of directory.

So the import become this :

```
import "google_annotations.proto";
import "nakama_annotations.proto";
import "nakama_api.proto";
```

The reason that I put `protos` in front before because the Android Studio plugin doesn't show red highlight when I put like that. Now After remove that, it highlight red, but it works.